# Ruby on Rails - dynamic navigation with link_to in a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, navigation, link-to

I want to add navigation to a series of div, which are loaded dynamically.
For this I am using link to covering the div and passing it the attribute to the method.
The problem is that when I press on the div the attribute does not correspond. 
I put the code.
With this code all it's ok, but i don't have the link in the div.

```
 <%for i in inicio..final %>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="tarjeta_comercio">
  <%= link_to 'mezcla/mostrar_institucion', {:controller => "mezcla", :action => "mostrar_institucion", :institucion_actual => @institucions[azar[i]].id} %>
      <div class="foto">
        <%= image_tag @institucions[azar[i]].logo.url(:original) %>
      </div>
      <div class="titulo">
        <%= @institucions[azar[i]].nombre %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

But the problem is when i do a block with "link_to...do-div-end". If i do this the parameter don't run. I don't explain why this happen. This is the wrong code.

```
<%for i in inicio..final %>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="tarjeta_comercio">
  <%= link_to 'mezcla/mostrar_institucion', {:controller => "mezcla", :action => "mostrar_institucion", :institucion_actual => @institucions[azar[i]].id} do %>
      <div class="foto">
        <%= image_tag @institucions[azar[i]].logo.url(:original) %>
      </div>
      <div class="titulo">
        <%= @institucions[azar[i]].nombre %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In :institucion_actual each time put 0 (when i pulsed over).
Thanks.

Comment: What is azar? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: An array with random number. from inicio to final. For random order of elements

Comment: Where are you creating it?

Comment: tamTotal = @institucions.size
  azar = []
  inicio = 0
  final = tamTotal-1
  for i in inicio..final
    azar[i] = i
  end
  azar = azar.shuffle

Comment: azar its ok, this isn't the problem.

Comment: If it's in the controller you need to make it an instance variable by appending @ otherwise it's not available in your view. This is why i was asking.

Comment: azar is a variable of class